# Why offsetWidth different for the same character?

Tags: javascript, dom

I encountered this example in [chapter 14 of Eloquent Javascript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/14_dom.html).

```
<p><span id="one"></span></p>
<p><span id="two"></span></p>

<script>
  function time(name, action) {
    let start = Date.now(); // Current time in milliseconds
    action();
    console.log(name, "took", Date.now() - start, "ms");
  }

  time("naive", () => {
    let target = document.getElementById("one");
    while (target.offsetWidth < 2000) {
      console.log(target.offsetWidth); // added to see changes of target.offsetWidth
      target.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
    }
  });
  // → naive took 32 ms

  time("clever", function() {
    let target = document.getElementById("two");
    target.appendChild(document.createTextNode("XXXXX"));
    let total = Math.ceil(2000 / (target.offsetWidth / 5));
    target.firstChild.nodeValue = "X".repeat(total);
  });
  // → clever took 1 ms
</script>
```

By adding `console.log` in the `naive` version of `time` function, I found the `target.offsetWidth` does not increase by the same amount each time I add an X character. So the eight `target.offsetWidth` are

```
12
23
35
46
58
69
81
93
```

It looks to me that X character sometimes takes 11 pixels and sometimes 12. I guess this is the reason why the `clever` version of `time` function needs to first prints five X characters and divide them by five to get an accurate estimate of how many X characters we need to print.

But if so, why is it the case that the same character can take different pixels on the screen?

Comment: Probably because you're not using a monospaced font. Characters don't always take the same amount of space.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Just googled what it is. But for proportional fonts, would they make the same characters of different pixels as well? What’s the intention behind such design?

Comment: Basically, it's a design thing (and I barely match my socks most days). There are times where it makes more sense to combine letters together (for instance the `f`'s overhang can be placed over the `o` in "for"). There is also this thing where characters don't line up to the pixel grid and have to be moved so that they line up, so that can affect how many of the same character fit in a certain number of pixels. Weird stuff, I know.